# Mass action law remain with finite particle volumes

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Typical discussions of the mass-action law I've read do not consider explicitly the volume of the particles. It is clear as the particle volume increases, the system transitions to a "jammed" state and reactions stop occurring.

Does the mass action law break down in this regime? What is the effect of finite particle volumes in the mass action law?

Comment: Molecules are not hard spheres with a well defined volume and as you try to increase the density of your mixture this approximation will break down. You will have to explicitly take account of how the elections in the molecules interact with each other and form bonds. What will happen at your "jamming point" is that the mixture will freeze into a solid.

Comment: @BySymmetry Which assumption of the ones made in the derivation of mass-action breaks down?

Comment: I mean that your questions assumption that you can treat molecules as hard objects with a definite volume breaks down